# Unable to resolve dependency for project under test + asp.net core rc2

Tags: asp.net-core

Since the upgrade to rc2, the integration test project which had a dependency to the webapi project is no longer resolvable. Has this changed with rc2 or is there an issue in how the webapi project is configured after the upgrade? The documentation listed on web has the webapi dependency listed in the test project. Are there alternatives to testing the api without the need to reference the webapi project?

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the upgrade process some of the projects that were referenced in the api project had references to the dnx targets which caused a conflict. I have since updated the xproj to refer to the DotNet props/targets and the api project is resolvable.